# cooked beef patty at 250F/120C, is it safe to eat?

Tags: beef, ground-beef

I'm pretty new to this and I don't have a thermometer, so I decided to cook the beef patties (1/5 a pound each, 6 total) a few minutes on each side in the pan, then 1 hour at 250F in the oven wrapped in aluminium foil, is it safe to eat? the inside looks a little pink

Comment: You can't know whether it's safe if you don't have a thermometer, sorry. Think of food safety as akin to a certification system: you only get the certificate "safe" if you fulfill the formal requirements, in this case by measuring the temperature. It can be useful to read our basic info on food safety, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info.